# When two variables is logically compared, the logic gate that tests the equivalence is? Using logic gate

Tags: binary, xor, binary-data, truthtable, number-systems

When two variables is logically compared, the logic gate that tests the equivalence ..
If XOR  please explain Why ?
if XNOR Please explain Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `XNOR`. As for why, just look at the truth table for 2 inputs:

[image: truth table of XNOR]

You see that it returns `1` if either *both* inputs are `1` or *both* inputs are `0`, or in different words, when the inputs are of the same value. This can be described as checking for equivalence.

This can also be seen by looking at what `XNOR` means: "eXclusive Not OR". That means that it is the opposite of checking whether exactly one input is `1` (since "exclusive OR" means either one of the outputs may be `1` but not both), i.e. checking whether either none or both of the inputs are `1`, i.e. checking whether either both inputs are `1` or both inputs are `0`, i.e. whether both inputs are equivalent.

(It can also be called `NXOR`, which in my opinion is clearer. Because an exclusive OR of two inverted values would give the same result as without the negation, but this is the inversion of an exclusive OR.)